# How to understand electronic circuits?

Tags: microcontroller, design, embedded

My question's title might seem too common but I do want to know how these circuits work. People suggest to read books like 'Getting started with electronics' or 'The art of electronics' but these only explain about circuit elements and their analysis inside a network.

I am a complete beginner & have tried to read some books about embedded systems but can't get how to arrange various components together to support a microcontroller. Such as if we want to make an oscillator circuit or a counter to support a chip, how does one arrange resistor of a specific value and why? Or why the hell we put resistors & capacitors together in a circuit to achieve something. Suppose I'm constructing an alarm system with a microcontroller, how do I build the circuit, how do I even start?? Take an example of a handheld game console(such as the GameBoy), upon what decision the elements were chosen (and how circuit elements were arranged), how do they know that the circuit will work by arranging those in such a particular arrangement?

I'm completely clueless about them. Sorry for my confusing language, please guide me if I'm proceeding in the wrong direction.

Comment: You need to start with these circuit elements and their analysis inside a network to understand which components are needed in larger, embedded systems such as your alarm system.  Patience and persistence is vital.  You can't become a chef without ever tasting rice.

Comment: Simulations, experience, and knowledge.  It takes a long time to master all those circuit elements but without doing any kind of simulations in lab, you will not know how a circuit element behaves.  By building simple circuits, you will eventually learn to combine more circuits together to provide the correct amount of power, voltage, current, etc.  So get your hands dirty and simulate.  To know the exact behaviors of every elements, you will need to read books and books

Comment: You know, Electrical Engineering is actually a 4-year program in Universities? And considered to be a hard one.

Comment: As @EugeneSh. says, and after that you still won't be able to design anything substantial without a bunch more experience. The 4 years just gives you some math and theory background to understand what you have to learn.

Comment: I'm not questioning about the level of this study, just wondering about real world practice. Even I'm an electronics student but how it is taught at my college makes it difficult to relate with practical applications.

Comment: *I'm completely clueless about them* That's because you want **too much** all at once. It is like you just learned how a wheel works and now want to design and build your own car. You start simple and then work your way up. Real world practice is that you **do things**. The theory and skills you learn at college and University are the basic tools and skills that you need to progress further into practical design. You progress at a job and/or hobby projects.

Comment: That confirms I'm in the right direction and not expecting too much.

Comment: I made circuits with blinking LEDs when I was 12, at 16 I could make a microphone amplifier, at 22 I could design a light ornament for art thingamabob and a switched mode power supply. At 30 I worked on RF chips at 200 MHz. At 40 I worked on on-chip circuits at 2.5 GHz and switching power supplies. Now at 48 I do toplevel design for a radar chip at 80 GHz. See, I work my way up. It takes time :-)

Comment: I think this is actually a question about creativity and problem solving: how do I build X given a blank page? This is kind of a separate, generalist skill. Knowing the existence of various techniques, how do you combine them? This is definitely something that requires *practice*.

Comment: Don't think about the Gameboy right now; get a bunch of components and a breadboard and a multimeter. Build a few beepers, flashing lights, guitar effects - stuff like that. Don't knock books like 'The Art of Electronics' - try and learn whatever you can from them. As for the blank page problem, learn to divide and conquer ie given I need to do X, I can break that down into A connected to B. A can be broken down into c and d. I know how to do c, and I saw something about d in 'The Art of Electronics' . . . .

Comment: You might gain some insight on practical EE design watching some of the [EEVblog videos on youtube](http://www.youtube.com/user/EEVblog/videos).

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to start from the basics: Ohm's and Kirchoff's laws.

You'll have to look at hundreds or thousands of circuits and analyze their behavior. It's impossible to design a circuit if you have never analyzed any and have no idea of how to achieve your desired functionality.

Electronics is an art as well as a science. You have to make a *lot* of mistakes before you will gain sufficient intuition to design circuits. I've been doing this for years, and I still constantly make mistakes. (I didn't even type this sentence correctly when I first submitted this post. Electronics design is harder than typing.)

It could take a designer hours to explain why they chose a specific value for one specific component in a subcircuit. It is not feasible to explain how an electronic product is designed in full. It's an iterative process of requirement definition, design, test, and validation of requirements.

Start simulating circuits. Download LTSpice, it's free.